# C# Documentation - User Defined Tags

Tags: c#, xml, documentation

I want to document my source (C# sources), indeed I use XML documentation tags defined. How I can define by specific tags?

For example I use a lot Design by Contract assertions. I'd like to have documentation sections
for preconditions, postconditions, invariants...
It should be desiderable to write documentation like:

```
/// <precond>arg != null</precond>
/// <postcond>return > 0</postcond>
```

Since I'm not an XML guru, someone of you (gurus) coould advice me?

I tried to use < include >, but it's impossible (to me) to have documentation built correctly.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a reason you could not simply include that info in the `<param name="args">` and `<returns>` content?

Comment: Yes. Simplest precondition imply direct parameter connection; in this case you're right. But classes could be more complex, and methods could be called only on certain class states... describing it without underlaying pre-post conditions could be a pity, especially when all my classes have defined with DBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) to build the documentation and its **[custom tags](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/content/extensibility.htm)** might be a solution. One problem with NDoc is the development stopped a while ago.

[Sandcastle also supports custom tags](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/archive/2006/11/22/supporting-custom-tags-in-sandcastle.aspx), I'm not sure if that works Sandcastle Builder though if that is an issue.

Both are done by customising the default XSL either uses for its transform, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="myTag" mode="seealso-section">
    <h1 class="green">
         <xsl:value-of select="." mode="slashdoc"/>
    </h1>
    </xsl:template>     
    <xsl:template match="null" mode="slashdoc">
    <xsl:text> null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML (`csc.exe /doc`) that is built by the compiler has no namespaces enforced in the tags, so you are free to use any tags you like.

Answer (score 5):

First a [very usefull description](http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html#para) of what is possible with xml comments.

Next thing is, that the applications generating your documentation have to be aware of your self made tags. I'm currently not aware of a documentation builder that can be extended with additional attribtes or elements.

Comment: I know how to document C# code. You're stating that is not possible to extent documentation tags, without at least an iteration with the software generating documentation?

Comment: Both NDoc and Sandcastle support extended tags. NDoc always has since its release

Comment: The link that supports this answer is broken, and Sandcastle *does* support customization of the associated `main_sandcastle.xsl` file to add in self made tags.

Comment: @atconway A broken link after three and a half year is a reason for downvoting?

Comment: Yes. The answer is not locked in time and neither are votes. Since the support of your question was partially based off a post which no longer links, to me it's a bad answer. This is another reason the FAQ really discourages just 'link posting' on SO. Basically your post now should start at: *"Next thing is..."* Even there, the answer is still wrong. Sandcastle *does* allow additional attributes, and has since before your post, so it was incorrect in 09' http://bit.ly/16GOsVA (article is from 06')

Comment: @atconway As far as I can follow your argument regarding the link I'm surprised how the statement "I don't know any" can be wrong if there are some. It is not helpful, indeed, but nevertheless it is correct. Anyway... feel free to downvote year old answers on already answered questions. Kind of useless in my view.

Comment: *"I'm currently not aware of a documentation builder that can be extended with additional attribtes or elements."* This statement was incorrect from the get-go. Look at the 2 upvoted comment on this post. I'm sorry this is to your dislike, I'm not doing anything outside the bounds of how SO is intended to work. You might want to propose on Meta that votes are locked after a period of time to preserve the essence of a certain time, but I don't think it will go far. Just a suggestion if you feel strongly about this.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful so long after the original question, but here is the last saved copy (from 2009) of the page in this response: https://web.archive.org/web/20090604112954/http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html

Comment: @meataxe It's useful for everyone looking for it. Thanks for adding it.